# phrase replacement

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary, synonyms, phrasing

I sometimes use common phrases that I'd rather spruce up with a single word or more direct phrase, or perhaps just by using fresher wording. One phrase I'd like to change is: "was the fact that."

My sentence is: "Mentioned in the article was the fact that international waters are so vast it would be impossible to use navies to protect the area [from piracy]."

Comment: The first problem is that _was the fact that_ is not a phrase. It's just a string of words that includes parts of several constituents and occurs when they occur together. There's a clause introduced by _that_, and there's a predicate noun phrase _the fact_ accompanied by a past tense auxiliary verb _was_, but no subject -- although it's predictable that the subject would be an extraposed dummy _it_. So there's a whole lot of syntax involved in generating this string of words, but it's not a syntactic constituent itself.

Comment: What you may be asking about is the difference between the factive NP complement construction _the fact that `S`_ versus a straightforward `S`. Compare _He denies the fact that the Earth is spherical_ with _He denies that the Earth is spherical_, and then change _spherical_ to _flat_. A Factive construction is one that [presupposes](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Presuppositiontriggers.pdf) its complement, like _He was not aware that she was present_, which entails she was present, versus _He did not think that she was present_, which entails nothing about her presence.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you seemed to not understand my question. Thank you for the try, though.

Comment: You're welcome. But nobody else seems to have understood it either, it appears.

Comment: Daniel Harbour seemed to have understood it.

Answer (score 2):

I share your reluctance to use *the fact that*, as I generally find that its near redundancy can be made totally redundant with some gentle rephrasing.  In this case, how about just avoiding the passive:

> The article mentioned that the international waters are so vast that it would be impossible to use navies to protect the area.

Alternatively, maintaining the passive, you could use a nominalization instead of a subordinate clause:

> Mentioned in the article was the impossibility of using navies to protect the area, as the international waters are so vast.

Or a more succinct version of the same structure, eschewing the *as* clause:

> Mentioned in the article was the impossibility of using navies to protect so vast an expanse of international waters.

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Harbour, I appreciate your answer. I should have rephrased my sentence. Your first example fits my style, typically, and, inadvertently perhaps, answers my question in part. I should have defined "fact" more precisely. I see how by using a more accurate word I would have been clearer in my statement and would have avoided "the fact that." Nevertheless, I am still wondering if there were a single word which could replace that phrase, in general, or if in avoiding it, I need to more clearly identify whatever "fact" replaced, as you did with the word "impossibility"?